# Why isn't my listview getting populated with workers?

Tags: c#, winforms

So inside private void listBoxWorkerType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) i'm trying click either a production worker or a QA worker and based on that, it will populate the listview with the e-mails of the production or QA workers. But it's skipping straight to "Please select a worker type.

The full code is:

```
https://pastebin.com/KgEACdSM
using BusinessEntities;
using BusinessLayer;
using DataAccessLayer;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace ProductTracking
{
    public partial class formFloorMAssignWorker : Form
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> workerType = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        #region Instance Attributes
        private formContainer fc;
        private IModel Model;
        #endregion
        #region Constructors
        public formFloorMAssignWorker(formContainer parent, IModel Model)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MdiParent = parent;
            fc = parent;
            this.Model = Model;
 
            // Add event handler for listBoxWorkerType's SelectedIndexChanged event
            listBoxWorkerType.SelectedIndexChanged += listBoxWorkerType_SelectedIndexChanged;
 
            // Add "Production" and "Quality" options to the listBoxWorkerType
            listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Production");
            listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Quality");
 
            // Display work orders
            Model.populateOrders();
            DisplayWorkOrders();
        }
 
        #endregion
 
        public formFloorMAssignWorker()
        {
 
 
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
 
        private void formFloorMAssignWorker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Model.populateOrders();
            DisplayWorkOrders();
            workerType[0] = "Production";
            workerType[1] = "Quality";
            listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Production");
            listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Quality");
            listBoxWorkerType.SelectedIndexChanged += listBoxWorkerType_SelectedIndexChanged;
 
 
        }
        private void DisplayWorkOrders()
        {
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.DataSource = Model.OrderList;
 
 
            // format the column header
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Goldenrod;
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
 
            // format the odd numbered rows
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod;
 
            //add new column for buttons
 
            DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            buttonColumn.HeaderText = "Assign Worker";
            buttonColumn.Text = "Assign Worker";
            buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridViewWorkOrders.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
 
        }
 
        //private void UpdateListView(List<IUser> users)
        //{
        //    // clear the list view
        //    listView1.Items.Clear();
 
        //    // add new user items
        //    foreach (IUser user in users)
        //    {
        //        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(user.Name);
 
        //        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        //    }
        //}
 
 
 
 
        private void dataGridViewWorkOrders_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            bool nextForm = false;
            int temp = 0;
 
            // Check each column to find the 'Assign Worker' button column
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridViewWorkOrders.Columns)
            {
                if (column.Name == "columnButton" && e.ColumnIndex == column.Index)
                {
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewWorkOrders.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[column.Index].Value.ToString());
                    break;  // Exit the loop once the 'Assign Worker' column is found
                }
            }
 
            foreach (Order t in Model.OrderList)
            {
                if (temp == t.WorkOrderID)
                {
                    Model.CurrentOrder = t;
                    nextForm = true;
                }
 
                if (nextForm)
                {
                    formFloorMAssignWorkerAssign form = new formFloorMAssignWorkerAssign(fc, Model);
                    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    form.Show();
                }
            }
        }
 
 
        //private List<IUser> GetUsersByType(string userType)
        //{
        //    List<IUser> users = DataLayer.GetUserTypeFromDB();
 
        //    // filter for user type
        //    List<IUser> filteredUsers = users.Where(user => DataLayer.GetUserTypeFromDB(user.UserID).Equals(userType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
 
        //    return filteredUsers;
        //}
 
 
 
 
 
 
        private void labelWorkerType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void listBoxWorkerType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
 
 
            // Get the selected worker type using null-conditional operator
            string selectedWorkerType = listBoxWorkerType.SelectedItem as string;
 
            // Check if a valid worker type is selected or not
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedWorkerType))
            {
                // Clear the listViewUsers before repopulating it with new user information
                listView1.Items.Clear();
 
                // Retrieve users of the selected type and populate the listViewUsers
                foreach (User user in Model.UserList.Where(user => user.UserType == selectedWorkerType))
                {
                    // Create a ListViewItem to represent each user
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(user.Email);
                    item.SubItems.Add(user.Email); // Add user's email as a sub-item, you can add more details
 
                    // Add the ListViewItem to the listViewUsers
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a worker type.");
            }
        }
 
        private void labelAvailableWorkers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
 
 
        }
        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
 
 
 
        }
 
        private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
    //public formFloorMAssignWorker(formContainer fc, IModel model)
    //{
    //    InitializeComponent(); // Initialize the form's components
 
    //    this.fc = fc;
    //    this.model = model;
 
 
    //}
}
```

I tried debugging it and setting breakpoints and I think that it sees the  string `selectedWorkerType = listBoxWorkerType.SelectedItem as string;`
as an empty string, even though i'm pretty sure I populated it correctly the form_load:

listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Production");
listBoxWorkerType.Items.Add("Quality");

The user list looks like this:

```
using System;
namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public interface IUser
    {

        int UserID { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Password { get; set; }
        string UserType { get; set; }
        string Email { get; set; }
        string PhoneNum { get; set; }
        string Address { get; set; }






    }
}
```

Comment: Try to clean your code and post only what is relevant. You have duplicate assignments / items added to a ListBox (adding strings when you already have a Dictionary that contains those values). You also have a call to `InitializeComponent()` in `Form.Load` (??) and the same call in the default Constructor and in another, custom Constructor (which should just call the former as `public formFloorMAssignWorker(formContainer parent, IModel Model) : this() { \\ [...] }` )

Comment: Is formFloorMAssignWorker_Load even called? And yes please only show the minimal needed code to understand the problem. Its convoluted with code how to setup/use Listviews/GridViews etc. now and other weird stuff i fell liking i should call them out but thats not part of your question.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was messing around with different things, that's why it's like that. Basically the only part of the code i'm worried about is the listbox which is where I click one of the two types of worker, and the listview where I want the emails of the workers to appear if they match the userType of IUser.cs

Comment: Please clarify. Your question title is **why isn't my ListView getting populated with workers** but you seem to be asking why **it's skipping straight to "Please select a worker type"** in response to `SelectedIndexChanged` which suggests you're clicking on _something_. Is it a worker or something else? Since you can start more than one question thread here, try to boil this one down to 10-20 lines of code and a simple, focused question that helps move you to the next step.